# WebAPI Core, set a custom nuget/packge folder

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

I am trying to figure out how to override the package folder from the user folder to a custom folder location like inside my project folder

I have a webapi Core project with an appSetting.json

I read a few posts and may suggests using nuget.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <clear />
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="d:\\packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

I added in my WebAPI project which show along side with appsetting.json.

When I build the project, I see no package folder.

I also read about packages.config but I can't find that file anywhere.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nuget.config` file should be placed in a directory one level above the project and then it will work.

**For an example**,  the ConsoleApp152 folder is the folder which contains all your project files. And `nuget.config` file should be placed at the one level above the project files.

[image]

**When** you finish it, please close VS and then restart your project to enable this setting. And it will act on all projects in the directory level where the current `nuget.config` file is located and also all projects in the subordinate directories.